# If Statement with Multiple Empty Textboxes

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, conditional-statements

```
if (txtUserID.Text == String.Empty && 
    txtFN.Text == String.Empty && 
    txtMI.Text == String.Empty && 
    txtLN.Text == String.Empty && 
    txtUsername.Text == String.Empty && 
    txtPassword.Text == String.Empty && 
    txtConfirm.Text == String.Empty)
{
    XtraMessageBox.Show("All fields are required!", 
                        "Warning", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Hello Guys can someone give me the correct code of this. I want to see to it that if there's an empty textbox left when inputting data, the system will not continue unless it fills all blank textboxes :)

Comment: Change your && to ||. You want to enter into your if block if one of them is empty, not all of them. Check this out for more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691310%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have AND (&&), should be OR (||)

```
if (txtUserID.Text == String.Empty || txtFN.Text == String.Empty || txtMI.Text == String.Empty || txtLN.Text == String.Empty || txtUsername.Text == String.Empty || txtPassword.Text == String.Empty || txtConfirm.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show("All fields are required!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
```

Comment: Akemi needs all texts be filled and not at least one of them.

Comment: If one of them is empty, show a message box that says all the fields are required, this code is just fine

Comment: Oops, you are right. I was wrong. I changed my vote. I am sorry :).

Answer (score 1):

If just one empty textbox should be considered an error, then your need to change the && (AND) conditional operator to || (OR)

```
if (txtUserID.Text == String.Empty || 
   txtFN.Text == String.Empty || 
   txtMI.Text == String.Empty || 
   txtLN.Text == String.Empty || 
   txtUsername.Text == String.Empty || 
   txtPassword.Text == String.Empty || 
   txtConfirm.Text == String.Empty)
{
  XtraMessageBox.Show("All fields are required!", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be clearer with a little LINQ:

```
var textBoxes = new TextBox[] { txtUserID, txtFN, txtMI, txtLN,
                                txtUsername, txtPassword, txtConfirm };

if (textBoxes.Any(tb => tb.Text == String.Empty))
{
    // Show the MessageBox
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If all textboxes are in the same container you can use:

```
if(Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(t => t.Text == ""))
{
   //Show error message
}
```